# Retrofit 2.0 - unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am creating an android app that would upload data to a database using Retrofit2. When I submit the data it goes to the database, but an error always says this **unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface**. I tried searching for different solutions but don't seem to work.

This is my API Class:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RegisterAPI {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("insertText.php")
retrofit2.Call<Result> createUser(
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("age") String age);

}
```

And this is my InsertActivity Class:

```
public static final String ROOT_URL= "https://MYURL/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insertUser();
        }
    });
}

  public void insertUser(){

    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String age = editTextAge.getText().toString().trim();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    RegisterAPI service = retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);

    Call<Result> call = service.createUser(
           name,
           age
    );

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `javax.xml.transform.Result` is an interface, so, when you get a response, the `Gson` deserializer will try to convert the response to that interface that cannot be created.

To solve it, you can pass an implementation of `javax.xml.transform.Result`.

**By the way**, I'm pretty sure you are using the wrong import for `Result`.

Comment: Yes sir you are correct. Thanks again for the help!